# Best database for a Statistics System

Tags: mongodb, database-design, cassandra, redis, database

I need to build a Statistics System but I don't know if MongoDB would be the best solution. The system needs to track couple of things and than display the information. For example of a similar thing - a site, and every user that first visits the site adds a row with information about him. The system needs to store the data as fast as possible, and, for example, it creats a chart of the growth of users viewing the page using Google Chrome. Also, if a user visits again, a field in the users's already row is updated (say a field called "Days").

The system needs to handle 200,000 new visits a day (new records), 20,000,000 users visits again (updates) a day, and 800,000,000 DB records. It needs also to output the data fast - for example, creating a chart of how much users visits each day from England, using Google Chrome, etc.

So what would be the best DB to handle this data? Would MongoDB handle this fine?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you writing it yourself instead of using web analytic software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongodb allows atomic updates and scales very well. That's exactly what it's designed for. But keep in mind two things: beware the disk space, it may run out very quickly and if you need quick stats (like region coverage, traffic sources, etc.), you have to precompute them. The fastest way is to build a simple daemon for this that would keep all numbers in memory and save it hourly/daily.

Answer (score 3):

Redis is a very good choice for it, provided you have a lot of RAM, or a strategy to shard the data over multiple nodes. it's good because:

1. it is in memory, so you can do real time analytics (I think bit.ly's real time stats use it). in fact, it was originally created for that.
2. it is very very fast, can do hundreds of thousands of updates a seconds with ease.
3. it has atomic operations.
4. it has sorted sets which are great for time series.

Comment: I'd consider using Redis at least for the fast reporting part.  Everything stays in memory so it's not a good fit for general traffic logging.

Answer (score 0):

[RDM Workgroup](http://www.raima.com/products/rdm-workgroup/) is a database management system for desktop and server environments and allows in-memory speed as well.

You can also use its persistence feature; where you manage data in-memory and then transfer that data on-disk when the application shuts down so there is no data loss.

It is based on the network model with an intuitive interface so its scalability is top-notch and will be able to handle the large load of new visitors that you will be expecting.